# How to remove all items in a magento product collection?

Tags: collections, magento

Seems doesn't works:

```
<?php
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    foreach($collection->getItems() as $key => $_product){
        //product
        $collection->removeItemByKey($key);
    }

?>
```

$collection is still populated

Comment: Remove is too vague an action.  What are you trying to do here?  Remove items from a collection so they're not there the next time you iterate, or delete them so they're gone from the system?

Comment: just remove from collection, nothing more.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: adding after
`<?php foreach($collection->getItems() as $key => $_product){
        //product
        echo $_product->getName(); //returns "my product name"
    }
?>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's `clear()` method in `Varien_Data_Collection` class which clears the collection.

I'm not sure if the method exists in the time the question was asked, but it exists in Magento 1.7

Answer (score 14):

If you'd like to work with an empty collection, the best approach would be to load it with a filter that would always produce an empty set. Here's an example:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', 0);
```

Because Magento product ids start at 1, this collection would remain empty, until you add items to it with the addItem() method.

clear() and removeItemByKey(), on the other hand, will only trigger a second run to the database to refetch the data you don't want in there.

Comment: Yours is the best answer by far. Sucks that some doofus got the green check mark for an answer that doesn't work.

Comment: `removeItemByKey()` won't trigger second fetch of data from the DB. It simply unsets internal data array by key.

Comment: `clear()` won't trigger second fetch on itself, but it sets _loaded_ state of he collection to false, so any method from collection class which calls 'load' method will trigger fetch.

Comment: @AnatolyA.Kazantsev so if I do this: `$coll=$this->getLoadedProductCollection(); $coll->clear->addAttributeToFilter('my_attr',array('like'=>'55'))->load();` will that add an attribute to the filter for my collection? Or will that added attribute be ignored since it wasn't used when the collection was first loaded?

Answer (score 7):

You question doesn't make sense.  Running the following code

```
$c = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach($c->getItems() as $key=>$item)
{
    $c->removeItemByKey($key);
}

foreach($c->getItems() as $key=>$item)
{
    var_dump($key);
}

var_dump( "Done" );
```

results in only the word "done" being output (Magento 1.6.1).

My guess it something about **your installation** of Magento is making the call to $c->getItems(); trigger a reload of the collection.  So, you remove all the items, but then when you call your second `getItems`, the collection is refetched.

Comment: Why does second `getItems` trigger fetching? It calls `load`, then `load` checks if collection is loaded by calling `isLoaded`. But `removeItemByKey` doesn't reset that flag. Or do I miss smth?

Answer (score 1):

There's also a possibility to remove all the items without "fake loading" (in opposite to Shay Acrich's answer):

```
class MyCollection extends SomeCollection {

    // ...

    public function setEmpty()
    {
        $this->clear();
        $this->_totalRecords = 0;
        $this->_setIsLoaded(true);
        return $this;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Setting `_totalRecords` to `0` is required in order not to allow `getSize()` method to reload the collection.

Nevertheless, one needs to extend / modify a collection's code, because both the field `_totalRecords` and the method `_setIsLoaded()` are protected.

There should be noted, that if a particular collection ignores flags like `_totalRecords` and `_isCollectionLoaded` the above solution may not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection->clear()
```

should do the work.